# Oracle to fill the missing dates

Tags: oracle

This query is to find all time High Aum. I have a table which stores the unit balance of an investor.

NAV is populated in a different table on a daily basis w.rt schemes. But unit balance is only updated with the date on which there is a change in units. So I am finding difficult to get the All time high **AUM**. I guess filling the missing date and then joining with NAV table will help.

This is structure of table which stores Closing Units:

> **Process_Date    SchemeCode     Closing Units        PAN NO**
>
> 30-10-2014        210             120007.68         AAAAB1231F
>
> 19-03-2015        210             15000                 AAAAB1231F
>
> 24-05-2013        82              122745.406        AAAAB1231F
>
> 13-04-2015        82              25000              AAAAB1231F
>
> 31-07-2015        82              12000              AAAAB1231F
>
> 14-08-2015        82              18700              AAAAB1231F

Note:210 & 82 are schemecodes

Comment: Can you fix the formatting on the table?

Comment: done . i guess this is much clear

Comment: To format code and tables, it is best to use the "code" formatting (select the text and press CTRL+k  or click the **{}** formatting icon).

Comment: OK, pretend like you are in a different industry (but still as an IT professional), you don't know what AUM or NAV mean or what this table shows. Now read your post. Does it make sense to you? Then congratulations, you are a genius! Most of us are not. Can you please help us by explaining what this all means? What is AUM? What is High AUM? What is NAV? I don't see either AUM or NAV in the table, I only see closing units, so obviously more INPUT DATA is missing, and that shouldn't be difficult to add even if you don't know how to solve your problem.

Comment: Ok i am sorry i guess these investment terms will not be clear to every one and even for me if i was not working in this sector. Lets make it simple. Suppose closing units are the quantity of books i hold and the price of book per unit changes on a daily basis which is stored in another table.(for eg unit is 100 and price is 10 then 100*10=1000). So my problem is I only update the records given in the above structure when the number of units i hold is updated. And i my requirement is to calculate the the date and value on which my units*price went highest.